# Cantor type iterations in Mathematica

Tags: code

I am trying to draw the iterations of the IFS in which from an interval middle third is removed and in the resulting figure left line is shifted 1/6th to the right and right line is shifted 1/6th to the left.

The following code I tried, doesn't seems right from the output image:

```
    cantorRule = 
 Line[{{a_, n_}, {b_, n_}}] :> 
  With[{d = b - a, 
    np = n - 0.1`}, {Line[{{a + d/6, np}, {a + d/3 + d/6, np}}], 
    Line[{{b - d/3 - d/6, np}, {b - d/6, np}}]}]

Graphics[{CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05], 
  Flatten@NestList[# /. cantorRule &, Line[{{0., 0}, {1., 0}}], 6]}]
```

In the above code how to change the color of the left shifting and right shifting lines different in each step.[image]

**Update:**

```
cantorRule = 
 Line[{{a_, n_}, {b_, n_}}] :> 
  With[{d = b - a, 
    np = n - 0.1`}, {Line[{{a + d/6, np}, {a + d/3 + d/6, np}}], 
    Line[{{b - d/3 - d/6, np}, {b - d/6, np}}]}]

Graphics[{CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05], 
  Flatten@NestList[# /. cantorRule &, Line[{{0., 0}, {1., 0}}], 6]}]
```

I changed the code as above and got this image:[image]
How to get the end points of each intervals labelled?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark How it is used?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark `CantorMesh` is only doing the middle third rule, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For labeling you can post-process the output to inject `Text`s:

```
label = # /. l : Line[p : {{_, _}, {_, _}}] :> {l, Black,
      Text[Rationalize[#[[1]]], Offset[{0, -20}, #], {Center, Top}] & /@ p} &;
lines = Flatten @ NestList[# /. cantorRule &, Line[{{0., 0}, {1., 0}}], 3];
label @ Graphics[{CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05], lines}]
```

[image]

Needless to say, if you have many layers there won't be enough space to avoid overlaps.

For coloring, you can `Partition` the list of lines (starting from the second) and `Riffle` desired colors into each pair of lines:

```
coloredlines = Flatten[Riffle[{Red, Yellow}, #] & /@ Partition[lines, 2, 2, {-1, 1}, {}]]
label @ Graphics[{CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.05], coloredlines}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `RandomColor[2]` instead of `{Red, Yellow}` to color each piece separately:

[image]

Comment: Can the label font size be reduced?

Comment: @supremum, you can change  `Rationalize[#[[1]]]` to `Style[Rationalize[#[[1]]], FontSize -> 6]` or to `Style[Rationalize[#[[1]]], FontSize -> Scaled[.01]]` and adjust the numbers (6 , 0.01) as you like.